# Can person access to Graph API using access token of other Facebook account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My team developed a system which includes searching for Facebook profiles and pages via Graph API.
I want this actions to be made by a person who does not have Facebook account.

Can I simply provide access tokens to that person and server will make API calls on my behalf?
Is it even legal?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Search API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search):

> - Searches across Page and Place objects requires an app access token.
> - All other endpoints require a user access token.

Meaning, you don´t need a User Session for searching Pages or Places, but you do need a User Token/Session for searching User Profiles.

Information about the different Access Tokens and how to create them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/